# Strings to json in bash

Tags: json, bash

I've got the following string as a output from for-loop:

```
something1/value1 something2/value2
```

Now I need to convert it to json. Expected output:

```
["something1/value1","something2/value2"]
```

I tried this:

```
echo $var | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]'
```

But the result is ugly

```
["something1/value1\rsomething2/value2"].
```

How do I properly make json from my string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jq you just have to do

`echo $var | jq -R -c 'split(" ")'`

Comment: almost perfect. But my result is ["something1/value1","something2/value2\n"]. What about \n at the end?

Comment: just remove the -s option ; i edit my reply in consequencies